# Google APIs, maps or places for text search on businesses and parks etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-places-api

I would like text search functionality, the thing is I want general places to be searchable as well, (I.E not just businesess), I'd like beaches, parks even cities...

Is it possible to do this with just places or will I need to use both places and maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [parks](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) in the Google Places data

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_places-searchboxB.html) (search for "park")

It doesn't look like all of them are there.

Comment: WOW what a great link, thank you, and Wow so impressed with Places, it has everything on there :)! Perfect.